# transparent background image with non transparent text in a view

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to produce a look for my mvc application that has a property from my model as a transparent background image then the title and a description as the text on the image, but I want the children of the div to not be transparent. I've looked around the internet, and have seen a few different ways to do it, like changing the background rgba to a certain value, but I can't seem to get it to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Here's my code

```
      @foreach (var item in Model)
  { 

<div style="height: 250px; background-size: cover; opacity: .5; border-bottom: 3px solid #e3c340; background-image:url(@item.Image);background-size: 100% 100%;  " class=" hidden-md hidden-lg img-responsive">
    <div class="row" style="  background:rgba(56,255,255,0.1);;">
        <h1 style="font-weight:bold;" >@item.Name </h1>
    </div>





</div>

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't make the background-image be semi-transparent if it isn't semi-transparent itself.
Lowering an elements opacity will do the same for it's children, which is quite logical, but can be frustrating at first.

Try this for example:

```
<div style="background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);">
  <p>I am perfectly opaque!</p>
</div>
```

Here we set the background color to be semi-transparent.

If you want to do this with an image, you would need to put it on it's own layer like so:

```
<div style="position relative;">
  <div style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; background: url(/some/path/image.jpg); background-size: cover; opacity: 0.5;"></div>
  <p>I'm still opaque!</p>
</div>
```